# Как сделать срабатывания кода в 12 часов ночи с помощью фоновой службы

Tags: asp.net-core, background-task

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;

        public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            _logger.LogInformation( 
                "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Получается надо эту службу в 12 часов запустить, правильно ли я сделал? Есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: можно воспользоваться готовым решением quartz .net, которая сделает все необходимое, и не нужно будет запускать службу в 12 часов

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, спасибо!  попробую.